# Latex Error File `x.sty` not found

Tags: packages, miktex, pdfpages, winedt, paralist

I am using MikTex and WinEdt 8.1 on Win8.1 X64. I am trying to compile a tex file which was previous complied on another PC without any problem. But I am having multiple

```
LaTex Error: File `paralist.sty` not found
LaTex Error: File `pdfpages.sty` not found
```

and so on. I installed basic MikTex package, and it should automatically install any missing package but failed this time. The `WinEdt` console asked me to `Enter file name:` or `Type X to quit` or `RETURN to proceed`. So I am wondering how to solve this issue.

ps. I finally solved this issue by trying to download the missing packages multiple times as it is sometimes not able to connect to the package repository.

cheers

Comment: @Johannes_B I think the situation is not the same here.

Comment: What do you have in "MikTeX Settings" -> "Install missing packages on-the-fly"?

Comment: @karlkoeller where can I find `MikTex Settings`

Comment: @daiyue From WinEdt toolbar, the last button in the second row (MikTeX Options)

Comment: @karlkoeller I found `MikTex Options`, but I couldn't find an option `Install missing packages on-the-fly` there. But I found a tab called `Packages`, so I guess it is where I should go then.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a failure caused by inability to reliably connect to the package repository, solved by manual installation of missing file.

Comment: @daiyue No it's in the General tab, at the bottom.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the manual installation was still going through connection to the repository.

Comment: @daiyue -- okay.  however, when you do the installation manually, you have a bit more control over what happens when there's a timeout.  that's what i was thinking of.